# Creating stored procedure in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, stored-procedures, amazon-redshift

When creating stored procedure in redshift like below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_test() 
AS '
BEGIN
TRUNCATE TABLE TABLE_1;

INSERT INTO TABLE_1
SELECT COL1, COL2 
FROM TABLE_2
WHERE CONDITION='SAMPLE'; 
           
END;
'
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This gives an error `syntax error near 'SAMPLE'` because `single quotes is already used for stored procedure begin and end`. Also, here we would `not be able to replace single quotes in INSERT query to double` because redshift will consider it to be a column.

Few other posts suggests to use `$$` for stored procedure, however $$ is not supported in sql workbench.
Any work around for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried double-quoting the string?

```
WHERE CONDITION=''SAMPLE'';
```

Data Sample

```
CREATE TABLE t (id int, status text);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (42,'foo');
```

Procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_test() 
AS'
BEGIN
TRUNCATE TABLE t;
INSERT INTO t
SELECT 8,''new record'';            
END;'
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Test procedure

```
CALL sp_test();
SELECT * FROM t

 id |   status   
----+------------
  8 | new record
(1 Zeile)
```

Comment: @pc_pyr odd. what is the error message now?

Comment: @pc_pyr this is now a totally different issue and is unrelated to your original question. As the AWS doc says, try calling the procedure as a top-level call i.e. not from within an explicit transaction block: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-transaction-management.html

Comment: Thanks@ Jim Jones, please would you like to tell a little more about how to make a `top-level call`

Comment: @pc_pyr as I said, this is ins't related to your original question and we're not encouraged to answer multiple questions in a single post. So, you have to ask another question for that or take a look at `SECURITY DEFINER` in the link I mentioned above.